# How do I make an <a> element with text-selectable child elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, copy-paste, dom-events

I inherited some markup where a series of top-level `<a>` elements each contain a set of `<span>` elements, and using CSS, they're rendered as clickable blocks in a list, like this:

```css
.list {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  font: 14px Arial;
}
  .list a {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
  }
    .list a:last-child {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    .list a:hover {
      background: #CDE;
    }

    .list a .name {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .list a .secondary {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
      color: #678;
      font-size: 85%;
      padding-top: 2px;
    }
    
    .list a .address {
      padding-right: 16px;
      padding-left: 8px;
    }
    .list a .company-id {
      color: #B88;
      cursor: text;
      padding-left: 4px;
      padding-right: 4px;
      margin-right: -4px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <a href="/link/to/company/10101">
        <span class="name">Alice Jones &amp; Co.</span>
        <span class="secondary">
            <span class="address">55 Oak Street, Anytown 15151</span>
            <span class="company-id">#10101</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <a href="/link/to/company/12345">
        <span class="name">John Smith Inc.</span>
        <span class="secondary">
            <span class="address">123 Main Street, Anytown 15151</span>
            <span class="company-id">#12345</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <a href="/link/to/company/20123">
        <span class="name">Bob Johnson LLC</span>
        <span class="secondary">
            <span class="address">17 Spruce Street, Anytown 15152</span>
            <span class="company-id">#20123</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**The Request**

A product owner asked me the other day if I could make the company IDs *not clickable* — our users want to be able to *select* the text of the IDs for copy-and-paste.  Fine, I thought:  Turn each `<a>` element into an `<li>` like it should be anyway, add a little JavaScript to follow the links on clicks, and ignore clicks on the company IDs, and done.

Then I learned there's another user requirement — that the `<a>` elements must also be middle-clickable or Ctrl-clickable to open them in a new tab.  I intended to tweak the JavaScript to invoke `window.open()` if the Ctrl-key or middle-mouse button was down, but it seems that ad-blockers and browser popup blockers get in the way of that working reliably:  The `<a>` element needs to be a real `<a>` element, and its events must be left more-or-less untouched.  But that means that the `<a>` will capture every bubbling event on its content, including events I'd prefer it not touch, like the click-and-drag (and double-click) events on the company ID.

And since the list has a flexible layout, I can't put the company ID element outside the `<a>` element, and then appear to make it part of the same block using `position` or `margin` tricks:  The spacing won't work, because the IDs vary pretty widely in length (from `1` to `129370-5486`).

**tl;dr:** I need a child element to exist *inside* an `<a>` element for *layout* — but it needs to exist *outside* the same element for *behavior*.

---

**Requirements**

For a valid solution, I have to meet these requirements:

- The full `<a>` element must be clickable as a link, except for the company ID `<span>`.
- The full `<a>` element can be middle-clicked to open it in a new tab, except for the company ID `<span>`.
- A user must be able to click-and-drag on the company ID `<span>` to select and copy its text.
- A user must be able to double-click on the company ID `<span>` to select and copy its text.
- The layout must be flexible, allowing text spans of arbitrary length, and collapsing to the narrowest overall width.
- The solution must work in modern evergreen browsers (i.e., Chrome, Firefox, Edge — no old-IE compatibility required!).

Beyond that, the sky's the limit:  Dependencies, no dependencies, add/tweak the CSS, add some JS, change the markup — as long as those six bullet points are met, you can do whatever you want.

---

**My Best Solution**

I've tried an awful lot of JavaScript event-capturing tricks so far, most of which were failures.  The best working solution I've found involves no JS at all:  I include the company ID in the markup twice — once inside the `<a>` with `visibility:hidden` for layout purposes, and then again in the markup after the `</a>`, with a `position:relative`-containing `<li>` element around all of it, and `position:absolute / bottom: / right:` on the visible, selectable `<span>`.  But it seems like there ought to be a better way that doesn't involve mutating the markup; and if the product owners ever want more text in each box, or a slightly different layout, my solution is not likely to adjust to those changes very well.

So do you have any better ideas than I have for pulling off normal, selectable text elements inside an otherwise-clickable `<a>` element parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heydon Pickering wrote an article on [inclusive card design](https://inclusive-components.design/cards/) where it goes over how to handle selectable text inside a card component where the entire card is clickable.

One of the solutions that would work for you would be to change each of the `<a>` elements into `<li>` elements as you had, but then add an `<a>` tag around just the name of the company. Then you can add a pseudo element to the anchor tag that expands the full width/height of the parent `<li>`. Lastly, add `position: relative` to the id to bring it above the anchors pseudo element so it won't activate the link.

```css
.list {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  font: 14px Arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
  .list li {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
  }
    .list a::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  
    .list li:last-child {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    }
    .list li:hover {
      background: #CDE;
    }

    .list li .name {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .list li .secondary {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row nowrap;
      justify-content: space-between;
      color: #678;
      font-size: 85%;
      padding-top: 2px;
    }
    
    .list li .address {
      padding-right: 16px;
      padding-left: 8px;
    }
    .list li .company-id {
      color: #B88;
      cursor: text;
      padding-left: 4px;
      padding-right: 4px;
      margin-right: -4px;
      position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <a href="/link/to/company/10101" class="name">Alice Jones &amp; Co.</a>
        <span class="secondary">
            <span class="address">55 Oak Street, Anytown 15151</span>
            <span class="company-id">#10101</span>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/link/to/company/12345" class="name">John Smith Inc.</a>
      <span class="secondary">
          <span class="address">123 Main Street, Anytown 15151</span>
          <span class="company-id">#12345</span>
      </span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/link/to/company/20123" class="name">Bob Johnson LLC</a>
      <span class="secondary">
          <span class="address">17 Spruce Street, Anytown 15152</span>
          <span class="company-id">#20123</span>
      </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the link too ;)

Comment: I love that stretched pseudo-element trick!  I tend to forget that you can use top/bottom/left/right to stretch elements, not just position them.  This is hands-down the best solution I've seen so far:  The markup is clean, the CSS has very few oddities, and the whole thing is pure HTML-and-CSS.  Nicely done :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the related codepen I created but the psuedo-a is commented out in the js: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XyLgag

This should get you started but not exactly as you need I'm sure....  HTH

CSS:

```
a.psuedo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 0 !important;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

JQUERY TO COPY TO CLIPBOARD:

```
//Add custom event listener
$(':root').on('mousedown', '*', function() {
    var el = $(this),
        events = $._data(this, 'events');
    if (events && events.clickHold) {
        el.data(
            'clickHoldTimer',
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    el.trigger('clickHold')
                },
                el.data('clickHoldTimeout')
            )
        );
    }
}).on('mouseup mouseleave mousemove', '*', function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('clickHoldTimer'));
});

//Attach it to the element
$('.company-id').data('clickHoldTimeout', 2000); //Time to hold
$('.company-id').on('clickHold', function() {
  /* Get the text field */
  var copyText = $(this).html();

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");
  console.log("copied -- " + copyText);

});
```

JQUERY TO ADD PSEUDO-ANCHOR TAG

```
$(".company-id").each(function() {
    $(this).append('<a class="psuedo" target="_blank" href="www.google.com"></a>');
  });
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @SeanWerkema sure...  try this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XyLgag